# C function to sum two arrays of numbers?

Tags: c, arrays, function

Is there a function like `memcpy()`, to add the values in arrays? Something like `memconcatenate()` maybe?

If not, is there some equivalent way I could element-wise add the values of an array to another (other than using a loop) ?

EDIT: I think I made a big mistake by making up a function `memconcatenate()`. I **DO NOT** mean joining two arrays head to tail. I'm interested in **element-wise addition** . Like @user3386109 suggests, think: `memsum()`.

Comment: Is there a function like memcpy(), to add the values in arrays ?
memcpy will copy buffer from one location to other. which can be used for arrays also.

Comment: `memcpy(arr + currentElements, ...);`

Comment: If the input arrays are `a[3]={1,2,3}` and `b[3]={4,5,6}`, what would you want in the output array?

Comment: @user3386109 In that case I would want `a::{5,7,9}`. i.e., add the elements of `b` to those of `a`.

Comment: @AlterMann could you elaborate? I don't understand.

Comment: @physkets That's what I thought. So I would change `memconcatenate()` to `memsum()` in the question, since concatenate means that you want the output to be `a::{1,2,3,4,5,6}`, and that's what all the answers assume.

Comment: `int a[5] = {1, 2, 3}; int b[2] = {4, 5}; memcpy(a + 3, b, sizeof b);`, If you mean add to `a[3]={1,2,3}` then you can not, use dynamic memory : `realloc` and then `memcpy`.

Comment: @skrrgwasme et al. Could you tell me why the question is too broad? I would think that it is very specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a function like `memcpy()`, to add the values in arrays? Something like `memconcatenate()` maybe?

The standard library doesn't have any such function.

> If not, is there some equivalent way I could element-wise add the values of an array to another (other than using a loop) ?

I don't think there is a way to do that without using a loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard library function to do such thing as `memconcatenate`, but `memcpy` would help too. Suppose you have two arrays, and you want to concatenate them, if you want to place array `b` in the nth position of `a`:

```
int a[N];
int b[M];
memcpy(a+n, b, sizeof b);
```

But in this case you will need to make sure that the source array has enough space to hold the combined bigger array. Generally, you need to create a new array to combine two arrays:

```
int a[N];
int b[M];
int *c = malloc(sizeof a + sizeof b);
memcpy(c, a, sizeof a);
memcpy((char*)c + sizeof a, b, sizeof b);
```

To add two arrays, you will need loop, there is no other options:

```
int a[N], b[N];
int c[N];

for (int I = 0; I < N; I++)
    c[I] = a[I] + b[I];
```

This assumes the two array are of same size.

Comment: `c + sizeof a` is wrong.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yeah, c is of type `int*`, so it should be either `c+N`, or `(char*)c + sizeof a`. THanks.

Comment: Oh! Thanks, that is a nice use of `memcpy()`; I guess I used the wrong word when I said concatenate. What I want is element-wise addition of two similarly sized arrays resulting in an array of the same size.

Comment: @physkets in that case, you will have to use loop to add each element, see updated sample code.

Answer (score 0):

> If not, is there some equivalent way I could element-wise add the values of an array to another (other than using a loop) ?

Even if you have a function to do it, there will be a loop inside the function. Something like this.

```
 // elementsa is the no of elements in a.
 // elementsb is the no of elements in b.
 // The concatenated array is stored in a[]. 
 // You need to ensure that the array is big enough to hold (elementsa+elementsb)
 void memconcat(int a[], int b[], int elementsa, int elementsb)
 {
   int i;
   for (i=0; i< elementsb; i++)
     a[i+elementsa] = b[i];
 }
```

As per the later edit, you want to sum the elements. To do this will also require a loop. This loop can be inside a function, however.

```
// You need to ensure that a[] and b[] are of the same size,
// The output is stored in a[]
void memsum(int a[], int b[], int noelements)
{
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<noelements;i++)
     a[i] += b[i];
}
```